# OpenERP 7 API invoice validation and payment

Tags: php, api, xml-rpc, odoo

I am working with OpenERP 7's XML-RPC API and I am trying to validate an invoice and apply a payment but I can't figure out what model I should be using.

I have successfully created an invoice and added lines. There doesn't seem to be anything in account.invoice and account.payment.term and payment.order do not seem to work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i figured out how to validate payment to an invoice automatically via XML-RPC using php.

This how openERP invoice workflow works for the payment.

When you create an invoice, payment to this invoice is done by a voucher i.e. model account.voucher is used to apply a payment to an invoice. So when you create an invoice and validate it, the invoice changes status to open of which you can now access the "customer payments" menu and enter the customer name, the onchange_partner_id() function defined in account.voucher is executed to make a calculation of all the invoices the currently enter partner has open for payments.

Then when you enter the payment to make in "Paid Amount" field, onchange_payment() function is executed to allocate the amount paid to different open invoices of the selected partner.
And when you click validate on the payment form, automatically openerp pays the invoice and marks it as paid.

This therefore means you should atleast understand how openerp handles invoices and payments to that invoice by studying the python code in modules account and account_voucher To make the long story short, this is the code that i used.

- First create an invoice for a particular partner and validate it. make sure that you partner has a valid phone number set in res.partner model. (Just create it using openerp forms)

  ********************** *php code*  ****************

  ```
  <?php

  error_reporting(1);
  /*
   * TODO
   * Improve on handling of server responses. Success and Failures
   */
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
  include_once("openerp_models.php");
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //confirm that a username and password is set 
  if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) {

      //password and username -- Basic Authentication
      $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
      $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

      ///important parameters
      $phone_no = $_REQUEST['sender_phone']; //get the mobile number. Use this number to get the partner information.
      $amount = $_REQUEST['amount']; // get amount from url
      $amount_again = $_REQUEST['amount'];  //this will be displayed to the paying client. $amount above is reduced to zero hence
                                            //we create another amount variable to show the customer with success message.
      $payment_ref = $_REQUEST['k2_transaction_id']; // get this from url
      $firstname = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
      $lastname = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
      $middlename = $_REQUEST['middle_name'];
      $service_name = $_REQUEST['service_name'];
      $business_number = $_REQUEST['business_number'];
      $transaction_reference = $_REQUEST['transaction_reference'];
      $internal_transaction_id = $_REQUEST['internal_transaction_id'];
      $transaction_timestamp = $_REQUEST['transaction_timestamp'];
      $transaction_type = $_REQUEST['transaction_type'];
      $account_number = $_REQUEST['account_number'];
      $currency = $_REQUEST['currency'];
      $signature = $_REQUEST['signature'];



      //openerp instance, pass login,password,dbname and serverURL 
      $kengen_model = new OpenERPXmlrpc($username, $password, 'copia_training_db', 'http://127.0.0.1:8069/xmlrpc/');
      /* TODO UNCOMMENT THIS CODE FOR ACTUAL TESTING WITH KOPOKOPO SERVER
       * We will then authorize kopokopo to continue with record creation. But before that,
       * we should make sure that the request is actually coming from kopokopo using the signature value sent.
       * To learn more see https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api
       *
      //set up base string
      $base_string = "account_number=".$account_number."&amount=".$amount."&business_number=".$business_number."&"
              . "currency=".$currency."&first_name=".$firstname."&internal_transaction_id=".$internal_transaction_id."&"
              . "last_name=".$lastname."&middle_name=".$middlename."&sender_phone=".$phone_no."&service_name=".$service_name."&transaction_reference=".$transaction_reference."&"
              . "transaction_timestamp=".$transaction_timestamp.""
              . "transaction_type=".$transaction_type." "; 
      //get the symmetric key from table keys.api. This key should be copied from Your KopoKopo Account

      $get_key =  $kengen_model->search('keys.api', 'provider_name', '=', 'KopoKopo') ;  

      $key_id = $get_key[0];

      $key_value = '' ;
      //we read
            $read_keys = $kengen_model->read('keys.api', [$key_id]);
            //loop 
              foreach ($read_keys as $keys => $values) {
              $value = $values->scalarval();
             // print_r($value);
              //  print '<br/>';
              //$myarray [] = array($value['name']->scalarval());
              $key_value = $value['key_value']->scalarval();


          }
     // print $key_value; exit;
      //data to use
      $hash_data = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $key_value, true);
      //generate our own signature to compare with
      $signature_to_test = base64_encode($hash_data) ;

      ///test if the parameter $signature passed by KopoKopo is equal to $signature_to_test 
     // print $signature_to_test; 

       * TODO, DO the actual testing with Real KEY_VALUE and Request from kopokopo and only allow execution if 
       *  $signature_to_test = $signature else return an access denied status
       */

      /////////////////////////////////////////
      /* We retrieve the payment journal for kopokopo. We will 
       * use the journal code to retrieve the journal id. 
       * The code for kopokopo should be KPKPJ
       */
      $get_jrnl_code = $kengen_model->search('account.journal', 'code', '=', 'KPKPJ') ;
      $journal_id = $get_jrnl_code[0]; //kopokopo journal
      /*
       * We retrieve the account_id to pay to. This code is code for KopoKopo Account 
       * should be static i.e. 2040 is the account unless otherwise specified.
       */
      $get_acc_code = $kengen_model->search('account.account', 'code', '=', '2040') ;
      $account_id = $get_acc_code[0]; //kopokopo account
      //for this record to appear on list of customer payment
      $type = 'receipt';
      //

      /* TODO
       * after a successful login, we must authorize this user. We do this to make sure that 
       * the request if coming from kopokopo server.
       */

      //now search for the partner using phone/mobile number parameter
      $search_partner = $kengen_model->search('res.partner', 'phone', '=', $phone_no);
      //check to make sure that the customer exists
      //create an array
      $ids = array();
      //loop through the $search content and assign its contents to the $ids
      for ($i = 0; $i <= count($search_partner); $i++) {
          //   print $search_partner[$i];
          $ids [] = $search_partner[$i];
      }

      // if a user exist we continue processing
      if (count($ids[0]) > 0) {
          //perform a read, by picking the first item on the array
          $read = $kengen_model->read('res.partner', [$ids[0]]);
          // print_r($read);
          $myarray = null;

          $client_name = '';
          //this foreach loop with only loop once. hence just retrieve the client name and amount saved
          // in openerp 

          foreach ($read as $keys => $values) {
              $value = $values->scalarval();

              //  print '<br/>';
              //$myarray [] = array($value['name']->scalarval());
              $client_name = $value['name']->scalarval();
          }
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          //get invoices, pass partner_id and invoice status which is open for unpaid invoices
          //get invoices to retrieve the journal id   
          $get_invoices = $kengen_model->getPartnetInvoices('account.voucher', $ids[0], 'open');
          $retrieved_pay_account_id = 0;
          $pay_journal_id = 0;
          $period_id = 0;
          foreach ($get_invoices as $keys => $values) {
              $value = $values->scalarval();

              $retrieved_pay_account_id = $value[4]->scalarval();
              $pay_journal_id = $value[5]->scalarval();
              $period_id = $value[6]->scalarval();
              $move_id = $value[7]->scalarval();
          }
          //  print $retrieved_account_id; 
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          //fields to create
          $account_voucher_fields = array(
              'partner_id' => $ids[0],
              'amount' => $amount,
              'reference' => $payment_ref,
              'journal_id' => $journal_id,
              'account_id' => $account_id,
              //   'move_id' => $move_id ,
              // 'journal_id'=> $retrieved_journal_id, 
              'type' => $type);
          //voucher payment
              $create_kopokopo_payment = $kengen_model->createRecord($account_voucher_fields, 'account.voucher');
          //we get the total amount of invoice available for this customer.
          $total_invoices_amount = $kengen_model->getPartnetInvoices('account.voucher', $ids[0], 'open');
          $invoice_totals = 0;
          foreach ($total_invoices_amount as $keys => $values) {
              $value = $values->scalarval();
              $invoice_totals += $value[3]->scalarval();
              ///
          }

          //  print 'invoice totals is '.$invoice_totals ;
          //voucher line payment
          //we will retrieve all invoices available for this partner
          //get invoices, pass partner_id and invoice status which is open for unpaid invoices
          $invoices = $kengen_model->getPartnetInvoices('account.voucher', $ids[0], 'open');
          //loop through available invoices. Remember that a customer can have more than one open invoice
          $total_credit = 0;
          foreach ($invoices as $keys => $values) {
              $value = $values->scalarval();
              $number = $value[1]->scalarval();
              $invoice_amount_to_pay = $value[3]->scalarval();
              /*
               *  To undestand how this code works look at account.voucher model in openerp
               *  function recompute_voucher_lines(). This openerp function calculates voucher lines given
               * a particular payment.
               */
              $min_amount = min($invoice_amount_to_pay, $amount);
              //
            /*  print 'x';
              print 'on existing invoices in ELSE IF >>>' . ($min_amount);
              print '<br/>';
              print 'amount_unreconciled is >>>' . ($invoice_amount_to_pay);
              print '<br/>';
              print 'total_credit is >>>' . $amount;
              print '<br/>'; */
              ///
               //reduce amount paid
              $amount -= $min_amount;
              //convert amount into int
              $amount_to_allocate = intval($min_amount);
              // print $amount_total ;
              ///get invoice move line ids
              $new_number = str_replace('/', '', $number); //convert the invoice line
              $move_ids = $kengen_model->search('account.move.line', 'ref', '=', $new_number);
              /////
              $account_voucher_line_fields = array(
                  'partner_id' => $ids[0],
                  'voucher_id' => $create_kopokopo_payment, //last id inserted in account.voucher
                  'account_id' => $retrieved_pay_account_id,
                  'move_line_id' => $move_ids[0],
                  'amount' => $amount_to_allocate,
                  'type' => 'cr',
                  'name' => $number,);
              //////
                  $create_kopokopo_line_payment = $kengen_model->createRecord($account_voucher_line_fields, 
                         'account.voucher.line'); 
          }
          /*
           * we validate the payment. We access method button_proforma_voucher declared in model account.voucher
           * This methods validates an invoice payment and does reconcilation process for us if the user has paid
           * fully else the method reconciles invoice partially.
           */
          $validate_voucher_payment = $kengen_model->call_function_func('account.voucher', 
            'button_proforma_voucher', array($create_kopokopo_payment));  



          //customer found. Return a json response for KopoKopo
          $message = "Thank you " . $client_name . " for your payment of Ksh " . $amount_again . ". We value your business";
          // see doc @ https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api
          $success_response = array("status" => "01", "description" => "Accepted",
              "subscriber_message" => $message);
          echo json_encode($success_response);
          return json_encode($success_response);
      }

      // else we return a json_response with error message
      else {
          //customer not found. Return a json response for KopoKopo
          // see doc @ https://app.kopokopo.com/push_api
          $error_response = array("status" => "02", "description" => "Account not found");
          echo json_encode($error_response);
          return json_encode($error_response);
      }
  } else {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Copia ERP"');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      print 'Access Denied';
      exit();
  }

  ?>
  ```

  Hope this will help you.